# is there any working/real open source Plagiarism checker available?

Tags: plagiarism-detection

I want to develop a plagiarism checker for checking several source codes but I couldn't find any proper source code or even a resource to get an idea about it.
I have checked the Boss2 which is useless. they claim that they use Sherlock module for detecting plagiarism but it seems there is no such tools included in boss2.

if any open source detection tool is available for checking source code please let me know.
regards

Comment: These guys offer a commercial product that includes that capability, FWIW: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Duck_Software

Comment: https://github.com/architshukla/Plagiarism-Checker

Comment: For those who end up here I have also listed the available FOSS plagiarism checkers [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/opensource/comments/8xgldr/any_freeopensource_software_for_plagiarism/)

Comment: Add your comment as an answer please

Comment: This master thesis provides an overview of tools and methods in section 2.2: https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/355678/source-code-plagiarism.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y

Answer (score 5):

I'm aware of open-source plagiarism detectors for text (e.g., [WCopyFind](http://plagiarism.bloomfieldmedia.com/z-wordpress/software/wcopyfind/)), but not code.

> I couldn't find... even a resource to get an idea about it.

The authors of the excellent closed-source tool [MOSS](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/moss/) have published a helpful [paper about the technology](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/publications/papers/sigmod03.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old, but I did land here from a google.

Sherlock is an open source plagiarism detector.  [Sherlock's home page is here](http://www.cs.usyd.edu.au/~scilect/sherlock/)

Comment: In case the home page is down, there is a clone of sherlock on github https://github.com/kevinkjt2000/sherlock

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [SimiCheck](http://simicheck.com), and you are welcome to use it.  If you are interested in an API, I could probably write one very quickly.
I wrote the original algorithm as part of the [CrowdGrader](http://www.crowdgrader.org) peer-grading tool, but then I decided to make the comparison tools available independently.
[SimiCheck](http://simicheck.com) can handle code, Word (.docx), html, pdf, text, ..., as well as .zip, .tar, .gz, .tgz, and some more formats, and can deal with variable renaming, code moves, code across multiple files, etc.

Comment: Sorry Sir, but it is not a free and open source.